# Keras Movie Review Sentiment Classifier: What is the role of GlobalAveragePooling1D layer?

Tags: keras, text-classification

I was reading some IMDB movie review sentiment classifier on top of Keras. Here is the model definition:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```

What I don't understand is the role of GlobalAveragePooling1D here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer specifically why it's there (and not how it works), `model.summary()` will reveal that it is providing dimensional reduction.